# Prevent Rails 4 conversion of src url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to embed a video in a Rails 4 app using the following iframe:

```
<iframe src ="http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/4482208"> </iframe>
```

Right now I am serving the app from my local server (localhost:3000).

The app, however, automatically looks for the video at

```
http://localhost:3000/www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/4482208
```

I imagine this is because of the Rails asset pipeline?

I need the app to look for the video at its external location, at slideshare.net (not on my local server).

I am inserting the iframe as a dom object using jquery within a Backbone front-end.
Here is the code:

```
x = $(document.createElement('iframe')).attr({src: "http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/2686843" , frameborder: '0', marginwidth: '0', marginheight: '0', scrolling: 'no', allowfullscreen: ''})

$('body').append x
```

Comment: are you using `link_to` to generate this URL? Can we see some code

Comment: I am not using 'link_to'. I am simply creating a dom iframe object and inserting it (using jquery, within Backbone front-end).

    x =     $(document.createElement('iframe')).addClass('slideshare').attr({src: "http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/2686843" , frameborder: '0', marginwidth: '0', marginheight: '0', scrolling: 'no', allowfullscreen: ''})

Comment: I added the code to the end of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.src = "http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/4482208";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};
</script>
```

If this works, you can add other attributes like `frameborder`, `marginwidth` etc